# Making a conductive paint out of graphite powder

Tags: experimental-physics, electric-circuits, conductors, graphene

I want to make a conductive paint out of graphite powder and gum to use as an electrode. What shall be the best gum to use, as i need a low resistance of around some kilo Ohms. I am getting very high resistance. Should I use some solvent like ethanol? Is there anything else I need to know? I shall be putting it over PDMS.

Thanks

Comment: You need a high percentage of graphite,  as it needs to form a connecting network;  the denser the network, the greater the conduction.  [Here]( http://www.instructables.com/id/Conductive-Paint/) are some examples. Carbon nanotubes also work, and require less total carbon, if they are in the form of tangles; they are sometimes used to make conductive plastics.